# While Linux is rebooting which directory is used to search for the executable system binaries?

Tags: path, startup

While Linux is rebooting which `sbin` directory is used to execute the system binaries.

As per my knowledge it used to load the binaries in the directory `sbin` directory . But in my system I find so many `sbin` diretories , like `/sbin` , `/usr/sbin` , `/var/usr/sbin`.

Which file takes precedence?

Comment: Whichever the shell uses.

Comment: How Can I found the information ?

Comment: Read the documentation for the shell.

Comment: Can you please provide me good document regarding this ? I  gone through so many docs but i am unable to find these concepts .

Comment: Which shell is your boot process loading?

Comment: Iam using bash.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The choice of shell is irrelevant here. The shell doesn't set the path. Different parts of the boot process may use different shells anyway.

Comment: @Gilles: Some shells have their own default path. But of course, the startup routine doesn't even need to use a shell in which case the question is completely irrelevant to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I would cite from [FHS standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard):

> /sbin should contain only binaries essential for booting, restoring,
> recovering, and/or repairing the system in addition to the binaries in /bin.
>
> Programs executed after /usr/ is known to be mounted (when there are
> no problems) are generally placed into /usr/sbin. Locally-installed
> system administration programs should be placed into /usr/local/sbin.

Comment: While tangentially relevant, this doesn't answer the question, which is about the traversal order, i.e. the order in which the directories appear in `$PATH`.

Answer (score -1):

Reboot is done based on your PATH environment variables value,

Generally, it looks binaries based on the PATH env variable. If you use reboot then /sbin/reboot will execute if /sbin occurs in the PATH variable before other sbin's in PATH env variable.